# Can IntelliJ `make compile`?

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, makefile

I am working on a Java assignment, in the folder there's a `Makefile`, which looks like this

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard src/*.java src/*/*.java)

all: compile doc

compile: $(SOURCES) pre-build
    @@javac -d bin -Xlint:unchecked $(SOURCES)
    @@cp -r src/view bin/

doc: $(SOURCES)
    @@javadoc @doc_args $(SOURCES)

run: compile
    @@echo "Press 'p' to pause, 'r' to resume, 'cmd-q' to quit"
    @@java -cp bin RunningHeadline data_stream.json &

runcli: compile
    @@java -cp bin model.Feeder  data_stream.json &

pre-build:
    @@mkdir -p bin

clean:
    @@echo "Deleting all generated files"
    @@rm -rf bin/*
    @@rm -rf docs/*

diag:
    @@echo $(SOURCES)

.PHONY: all compile doc run runcli pre-build clean diag

help:
    @@echo "To run GUI client: make run"
    @@echo "To run CLI client: make runcli"
```

Can I `make compile` this file in IntelliJ?

I am using Windows system. Though I've got Ubuntu Bash in Windows, it doesn't have a good interaction compatible with Windows. Just wondered if I can achieve the same functionality in IntelliJ?

Comment: This is weird. It's *extremely* uncommon to use `make` for Java (Ant, Maven, Gradle).

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: A window pops up and displaying headlines of news sliding one by one. @LewBloch

Answer (score 1):

Basically this simple script does nothing else but compile some source files and provide different targets for executing the application.

And of course: any decent IDE and more advanced editors can take care of that.

The real answer: pick an IDE or more powerful editor and adapt the content of this makefile to match the features of that platform. What I mean is: don't focus on this makefile. Understand what you need, and then look out for that functionality in IntelliJ for example.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I make compile this file in IntelliJ?

Short answer: No.

A short search did not reveal any way to *run* a Makefile in Intellij ... but I may have missed something.  (I did find a Makefile plugin, but I think it only implements *editing* of Makefiles.)

If you want to use that Makefile to build your code, I suggest that you install a copy of `make` and a JDK.  Then run `make` from the command line.

But (IMO) you are probably better off ignoring the Makefile and building / running your code using Intellij itself.  Or better still, learn about Maven or Ant or Gradle and create the corresponding build files so that you can use those tools for building your code.

The logic of the rules in your Makefile are extremely simple, and you most likely don't need to learn about Make to figure out what they mean.

Final suggestion: ask your teacher!